# localhost:3000/my-scope/pages/new throws No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I got it!

```
   = link_to 'Zurück', page_path
```

That doesn't work in a new page. The page hasn't yet been created, so I can not go back to it...
This sure works fine in "edit", where the page exists

A good reason to spend the effort to get rspec to run :-)

Anyway, thank for the comments!

---

I got a little further....

**The routing seems to work. But my form seems to be the problem?!**

This is my view/pages/new.html.haml

```
= render 'form'
```

and it gets rendered if I do this:
    %p I should be a form for the new page...
    =# render 'form'

So it seems to be a problem with my _form.html.haml - which works fine for "edit"

```
= javascript_include_tag "#{root_url}javascripts/tiny_mce_head.js"
= form_for @page do |f|
  -if @page.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@page.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this page from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @page.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .field
    = f.text_area( :content, :class => 'mce_editor')
  .field
    = f.label :fan_only
    = f.check_box :fan_only
  .field
    = f.label :short_name
    %br
    = f.text_field :short_name
  .field
    = f.label :title
    %br
    = f.text_field :title
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
    = link_to 'Zurück', page_path
```

**Any ideas???**

I've already tried without the javascript_include_tag

---

**original post**

I can't create a new page anymore. It was working and I have no idea why it doesn't anymore!

If I browse to http://localhost:3000/pages/new

I get the following message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages"}
```

These are my routes

```
      scope '/my-scope' do
        resources :pages do
          resources :articles
        end
      end
      root :to => 'pages#index'
```

rake routes

```
    page_articles GET    /my-scope/pages/:page_id/articles(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
                  POST   /my-scope/pages/:page_id/articles(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
 new_page_article GET    /my-scope/pages/:page_id/articles/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
edit_page_article GET    /my-scope/pages/:page_id/articles/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
     page_article GET    /my-scope/pages/:page_id/articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
                  PUT    /my-scope/pages/:page_id/articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
                  DELETE /my-scope/pages/:page_id/articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
            pages GET    /my-scope/pages(.:format)                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"pages"}
                  POST   /my-scope/pages(.:format)                            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"pages"}
         new_page GET    /my-scope/pages/new(.:format)                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"pages"}
        edit_page GET    /my-scope/pages/:id/edit(.:format)                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"pages"}
             page GET    /my-scope/pages/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages"}
                  PUT    /my-scope/pages/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"pages"}
                  DELETE /my-scope/pages/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"pages"}
             root        /                                                    {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"index"}
```

controllers/pages_controller.rb methodes *show* and *new*

```
  # GET /pages/1
  # GET /pages/1.json
  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @page }
    end
  end

  # GET /pages/new
  # GET /pages/new.json
  def new
    @page = Page.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @page }
    end
  end
```

This is my view/pages.html.haml

```
%p#notice= notice
%content.viewmode
  = raw parse_content @page.content
-#if admin?
  = link_to 'Edit page', edit_page_path(@page)
  = link_to 'New page', new_page_path
  = link_to 'Destroy page', @page, :confirm => 'Are you sure to delete page #{@page.title}?', :method => :delete
  = link_to 'New article', new_page_article_path(@page)
-if @page.articles.empty?
  / 
    = "No articles for page #{@page.short_name}"
- else
  %ul.article_list
    = show_articles
```

I'd be glad if anyone could just give me a few ideas where to start searching.
I tried but I don't get any further.

Comment: Is that your entire config/routes.rb, or are their other entries you left out for brevity?  Also, why aren't you navigating to http://localhost:3000/my-scope/pages/new in your example?  is that just a typo/oversight?  or is that your problem?

Comment: Thanks! Yes typo, sorry, see comment below...
There is only the root in my routs.rb in addition. I added it above.

Answer (score 2):

You're using scopes, so your url should be `http://localhost:3000/my-scope/pages/new`